# failed to fetch libraries for openssh-server + Temporary failure resolving software sources

Tags: apt, ssh, openssh

I tried many ways like tried to find here gone through http://in.archive.ubuntu.com folders.

[image]

Comment: Packages are built for a specific release, and we don't know yours unless you tell us thus we're limited in what help we can provide. I do see `openssh-client | 1:8.9p1-3ubuntu0.4  | jammy-updates   | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` available but don't know if that's your release or what *architecture* you're using, NOR if you have -updates enabled.

Comment: You mention http://in.archive.ububtu.com but you probably mean https://in.archive.ubuntu.com

Comment: @Jos This is an irrelevant typo error in the body text. The software sources in the screenshot are legitimate.